# Functions and Transformation.

Tags: functions

> For $$f(x)=\frac{4x+5}{2x+1},$$ describe the transformation that changes $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ to $f(x)$.

So, on manipulation you get$

$$\frac{2(2x+1)+3}{2x+1}$$

$$2 + \frac3{2x+1}$$

The book I'm using took it off from here and said a vertical stretch of $3$ followed by a shift of "$-\frac12$" and a vertical shift of "$2$".

I didn't understand how they got it to $f(x)$ without considering the reciprocal. Please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: May be you can suppose that $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, then you find the appropriate $a,b,c,$ and $d$

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that it is simply a typo. It should perhaps read:

> Describe the transformation that changes $y=\dfrac1{2x}$ to $f(x).$

Then our manipulations are useful. The vertical stretch of $3$ changes this to $$y=\frac3{2x},$$ whence our horizontal shift of $-\frac12$ gives us $$y=\cfrac3{2\left(x-\left(-\frac12\right)\right)}=\frac3{2x+1},$$ and the vertical shift of $2$ gets us $$y=2+ \frac3{2x+1}=f(x),$$ as desired.